# What way did this person solve the problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics

[image]

Im curious, I have no idea how they solved the problem to get from the unitary vector to the Moment/Tension. How did they managed to get it so reduced? What steps did they perform in the blue part?

Comment: This is not "do-my-homework" -site.

Comment: It's not my homework. I'm studying for a test. I haven't managed to see the way they solved the unitary vector. But anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Mylane. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: [Moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) is *defined* to be the cross product between the force and the point at which it is applied (taking the pivot O as the origin). So which part confuses you?

Comment: Good morning, Mylane. The answer is actually correct. Many steps were left out between "Carry out & obtain" and the last line in the given solution. Basically I first took the cross product component by component (used the slater determinant method), squared the term with the sin inside the radical and then used trig identities to get to the final result.